# Request to Clear Caching Server Cache

Tags: node.js, express, flutter, networking, cache-control

I'm creating a character guessing game mobile application using Flutter, and an API using Node.js & Express.js as a back end. The mobile application is supposed to call the API to get all characters' categories from a MongoDB database, the API returns them to the mobile application (And caches them along the way for 1 day), the mobile app saves these categories with their data in an array, then calls the API once again to get a random character from the database.

The code of the API is like this:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

// Get All Categories
app.get('/categories/all', async (request, response) => {
  response.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400'); // 86,400 Seconds = 1 Day
  response.send(await mongodbDriver.getAllCategories());
});

// Get One Character Randomly
app.get('/characters/one/random', async (request, response) => {
  response.send(await mongodbDriver.getRandomCharacter());
});
```

The caching architecture is supposed to be like the image in the link:

https://i.ibb.co/S3wYkhd/Caching-Server-Architecture.jpg

If one day i added a new category, added characters to that category, and the API returned a random character with that new category, but the mobile app doesn't have data about it as when it fetched all categories the caching server responded with an old version of them and the character's new category wasn't among the fetched ones.

When that case happens i want the mobile app to send a request to clear the cache from the caching server either by sending the request to the Node.js API and the API calls a Cache clearing method, or by sending the request to the caching server directly. is something like this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround elhamdulillah. If I'm worried that i can get an old version of the categories array that doesn't include a new added category, and i queried for a random character and that character was returned with the new category that is missing from the array. I should make a third request to the API to get the category by ID and then add it to the array. That way the problem would have been fixed.